# C: How to use getc to avoid non UTF-8 characters being produced?

Tags: c, getc

I'm currently writing a c program that will take 3 arguments, two files (one input and one output) and an int (the max length of output lines, call it x). I want to read every line in the input file and write the first x characters to the output file (effectively "trimming" the file).

Here is my code:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

  const char endOfLine = '\n';

  if (argc < 4) {
    printf("Program takes 4 params\n");
    exit(1);
  } else {
    // Convert character argument [3] (line length) to an int
    int maxLen = atoi(argv[3]);

    char str[maxLen];
    char *inputName;
    char *outputName;

    inputName = argv[1];
    outputName = argv[2];

    // Open files to be read and written to
    FILE *inFile = fopen(inputName, "r");
    FILE *outFile = fopen(outputName, "w");

    int count = 0;
    char ch = getc(inFile);
    while (ch != EOF) {
        if (ch == '\n') {
          str[count] = (char)ch;
          printf("Adding %s to output\n", str);
          fputs(str, outFile);
          count = 0;
        } else if (count < maxLen) {
          str[count] = ch;
          printf("Adding %c to str\n", ch);
          count++;
        } else if (count == maxLen) {
          str[count] = '\n';
        }
        ch = getc(inFile);
    }

  }

  return 0;
}
```

The only problem is that if the last character is a single quote mark, it prints out non UTF-8 characters, as such:

```
For Whom t
John Donne
No man is 
Entire of 
Each is a 
A part of 
If a clod 
Europe is 
As well as
As well as
Or of thin
Each man��
For I am i
Therefore,
For whom t
```

Comment: You have undefined behaviour in the `else if (count == maxLen)` section where you overflow your array.

Comment: What is a non-UTF8 character for a data stream that contains single-byte characters?

Comment: @bvj Any 8-bit `char` not in the range 0-127 is not a properly coded UTF8 code point.

Comment: @rafro4 What is the value of `int maxLen` in your example?

Comment: `char ch = getc(inFile);
    while (ch != EOF) {` --> `int ch; while ((count + 1 < maxLen) && (ch = getc(inFile)) != EOF) {` for starters

Comment: @chux maxLen is 10

Comment: I've changed that but it no longer prints to the ouput file

Comment: `str[count] = (char)ch;
          printf("Adding %s to output\n", str);` occurs when `count == 10` given input `"For Whom t\n"`, so code is doing `str[10] = `\n`;`  which writes outside `char str[maxLen];`.  Also no null character appended before `str[]` is used in `printf("Adding %s to output\n", str);`, so `printf()` does not know where to end.  IMO, there is no UTF8 issues here.

Comment: @rafro4: Is there a reason you are not using wide input and output here?

Comment: the posted code does not, can not, will not output the example output that is posted.  Please post the actual output.

Comment: @user3629249 the posted code does, with the right input file

Comment: Is there anyway around this problem by using 'fgets' instead? I tried that initially but wasn't able to skip any characters after the first 10 to go to the next line (no assumptions about line length can be made).

Answer (score 1):

You could check if the last char output was a utf-8 continuing byte `10xxxxxx` and if so, keep outputting until the character is complete.

```
// bits match 10xxxxxx
int is_utf_continue_byte(int ch){
    return ch & 0x80 && ~ch & 0x40;
}

//...
while (is_utf_continue_byte(ch))
    putchar(ch), ch = getchar();
```

Comment: How would I go about doing so?

Comment: First, make `ch` an `int` so the `EOF` comparison is correct, then `while (ch & 0x80 && ~ch & 0x40) putchar(ch), ch = getchar();` This checks that bit 7 is 1 (`ch & 0x80`) and bit 6 is 0 (`~ch & 0x40`). For the utf-8 format, only continuing bytes fit this pattern.

Comment: Why write it as the more confusing `(ch & 0x80 && ~ch & 0x40)` and not `(ch & 0xC0) == 0x80`? And why avoid braces in loops?

Comment: For the first, it seemed conceptually simpler to test the bits separately, but yours is the way I usually do it. For the second, just a style choice.